I would like a mathjax expression for example sin{(x+y)} to show in an A-Frame enviroment
I use this Script:
<script type="module">
    import { fetchEnvValues } from '/scripts/fetchEnv.js';

    fetchEnvValues().then(envValues => {
        var latex = envValues[1] || 'x^2 + y^2';  // Verwenden Sie einen einfachen LaTeX-Ausdruck zur Fehlersuche
        var js = envValues[0];



        // LaTeX-Output in hidden Div rendern
        document.querySelector('#latexOutput').innerHTML = `$$${latex}$$`;
        console.log('LaTeX code set:', latex);
        
        // Check, MathJax is loaded
        if (typeof MathJax !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('MathJax is loaded');
            // MathJax bereits geladen, direkt typesetPromise ausführen
            typesetLatex();
        } else {
            console.log('MathJax is not loaded, waiting for window load event');
            // MathJax noch nicht geladen, warte auf das Laden des Fensters, um typesetPromise auszuführen
            window.addEventListener('load', typesetLatex);
        }

        function typesetLatex() {
            MathJax.typesetPromise().then(() => {
                console.log('MathJax typeset complete');
                const latexContainer = document.querySelector('#latexOutput');
                console.log('Rendered LaTeX innerHTML:', latexContainer.innerHTML);
                
                // SVG-Element aus dem MathJax-Container abrufen
                const svg = document.querySelector('#latexOutput .mjx-chtml');
                console.log(svg);       
                if (svg) {
                    console.log('SVG element found');
                    const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                    const svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
                    console.log('SVG:', svgString);

                    // SVG in VR-Element einfügen
                    const vrElement = document.querySelector('#latexVR');
                    vrElement.setAttribute('src', `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(svgString)}`);
                } else {
                    console.error('SVG element not found');
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error('MathJax typeset error:', err.message);
            });
        }
</script>

It seems that this line doesn't work:
const svg = document.querySelector('#latexOutput .mjx-chtml');

The return value is null. I changed .mjx-chtml for example to tex-svg an other. But no success. May be it exists another approach?

MathJax v3 and above doesn't have a .mjx-chtml element (version 2 did, but only the CommonHTML output, not for SVG output).  If you are looking for the SVG element, why not use
const svg = document.querySelector('#latexOutput SVG');

instead?  Or if you are just trying to typeset single expressions and capture the SVG output, you could use MathJax.tex2svgPromise() instead.  This will return the mjx-container element that contains the SVG element.
So you could do


<script type="module">
  const envValues = ['', '\\sin(x+y)'];  // faked fetchEnv.js
  
  function typesetLatex(latex, display) {
    MathJax.tex2svgPromise(latex, {display}).then((node) => {
      const svg = node.querySelector('svg');
      const svgString = MathJax.startup.adaptor.serializeXML(svg);
      alert(svgString);
    });
  }

  window.MathJax = {
    startup: {
      ready() {
        MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
        typesetLatex(envValues[1], true);
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js" defer></script>



for example without having to insert the latex into the DOM at all.
